# AS3, AlivePDF and open generated PDF in browser

Tags: php, actionscript-3, browser, filereference, alivepdf

Is it possible to generate a PDF with alivePDF and open it in a browser without using PHP?

Now I am using filereference class to popup a save dialog and then save to PDF, but I need to open the generated PDF in a browser. Is this possible? Throw navigateToUrl or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The decision whether the pdf is shown in browser or downloaded is taken by the client (browser) thus you don't have any chance to influence this behavior. The only thing you can do is force the client to download it - but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Looks like i have to use php for this one.